# Database Indexing

Tags: oracle, indexing

I'm trying to figure out on how to create an Index for below query such that the `SELECT` statement only traverse the leaf level of the index horizontally and it does not access the relational table. I'm working on a relational database in Oracle.

```
SELECT SUM(SUM(qty))
FROM PlaceOrder
GROUP BY OrderNumber
HAVING COUNT(LineNumber) > 10;
```

Am I correct to create the below index?

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_PO 
    ON PlaceOrder(qty, OrderNumber, LineNumber);
```

Thank you.

Comment: You should check an execution plan by yourself and see if Oracle uses this index or not

Comment: Please note that for index to be used a table should have `not null` constraint on `ordernumber` or you have to add this filter to the query. Otherwise Oracle cannot know that all the data is in the index, because all `null` tuples are not indexed

Comment: @astentx - I have deleted my answer as in testing I was surprised to see that the explain plan of query running a conceptually equivalent query on my DB of "having count(LineNumber) > 10" does a full table scan regardless of the fact that I have an exact index over the equivalent of (OrderNumber,LineNumber) - both are not null . I know that the CBO can behave differently for different data sets however I believe the data to be representative of the order, line table scenario.

Comment: @jillatiktik as I described above,  testing surprised me, so the best recommendation I can make is that you do an explain plan of your query without any index (making sure there is a reasonable size data set in your table. Then create the index on (OrderNumber) and redo the explain plan. Then add a new index (OrderNumber,qty) and do it again. Finally, add a new index (OrderNumber,LineNumber,qty) and do it again.  You may well find that in all cases the explain plan shows the index is ignored ie. full table scan (but please do let us know here either way as I'm interested to hear!)

Comment: @Pancho `not null` should be enforced either by constraint on the table, or by filter on a column in the query. Otherwise Oracle doesn't know if all the requested rows are in the index. Please check [this setup](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=faf812f40a0a6acbcc537c48cb220f46): index is used after explicit `not null` was added in any of the mentioned ways.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by astentx, `not null` constraint is needed. In fact, as long as any of `qty`, `OrderNumber`, `LineNumber` has `not null`, Oracle should be able to use the index.

Also, note that unless you specially want to exclude lines with null `LineNumber`, you can replace `COUNT(LineNumber)` with `COUNT(OrderNumber)` or even `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: Please read my answer regarding the index above: LineNumber is irrelevant for the index as ordering by LineNumber is not required in the query. Also the index is useless in its current form because qty has been made the first grouping column.

Comment: I have deleted by answer as surprisingly as per my comment in the question, testing indicates to me that "having count(..." causes the index to be ignored.